# Not able to enable tls in Java spring boot app in Openshift 4.3

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, tls1.2

1. I added JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD as secret in my namespace
2. Used inicontainer in my deployment to create keystore from tls key and cert gets generated using service annotation `service.beta.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name`. Initcontainer uses docker image `docker.io/abc/cert:latest` which is created from jre-alpine and installed openssl on it.

```
            - name: pem-to-keystore
              image: docker.io/abc/cert:latest
              env:
                - name: keyfile
                  value: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs/tls.key
                - name: crtfile
                  value: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs/tls.crt
                - name: keystore_pkcs12
                  value: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/keystore.pkcs12
                - name: keystore_jks
                  value: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/keystore.jks
              command: ['/bin/sh']
              args: ['-c', "openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey $keyfile -in $crtfile -out $keystore_pkcs12 -password pass:$JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD && keytool -importkeystore -noprompt -srckeystore $keystore_pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore $keystore_jks -storepass $JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -srcstorepass $JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores
                  name: keystore-volume
                - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs
                  name: service-certs
          volumes:
            - name: keystore-volume
              emptyDir: {}
            - name: service-certs
              secret:
                secretName: ${APP_NAME}-${NAMESPACE}-service-serving-cert-secret
```

3. updated application.properties

```
    server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
    server.ssl.key-store=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/keystore.jks
    server.ssl.key-store-password=${$JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
    server.ssl.enabled=true
```

4. updated Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT keytool -importcert -file /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts" -noprompt -storepass $JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD ; \ 
java $JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar
```

But I get error in the POD

```
keytool error (likely untranslated): java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password was working in the application.properties and in openssl command which I set myself. But it was not working in below Command I have in Dockerfile

`keytool -importcert -file /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts" -noprompt -storepass $JAVA_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD`

This worked when I used default password for keytool that is `changeit`
After that the error message gone and I can see `Certificate was added to keystore`

Another way is change the default password of the keytool and use it.